# charts_flutter ^0.6.0 version solving failed

Tags: flutter

While updating charts_flutter from 0.5.0

**Logs**

```
[myapp] flutter packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in myapp...                      
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.

Because charts_flutter >=0.6.0 depends on charts_common >=0.6.0 which requires SDK version >=2.1.0 <3.0.0, charts_flutter >=0.6.0 is forbidden.
So, because myapp depends on charts_flutter ^0.6.0, version solving failed.

pub get failed (1)
exit code 1
```

**pubspec**

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  charts_flutter: ^0.6.0
```

**Things I've already tried**

1. flutter clean
2. flutter update-packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.

...

> which requires SDK version >=2.1.0 <3.0.0

`2.1.0-...` is < than `2.1.0`

For `charts_flutter: ^0.6.0` you need a newer Flutter version.

Try

```
flutter channel dev
flutter doctor
flutter packages get
```

Comment: those commands work, but they move my environment from using a stable channel (Flutter 1.0.0 • channel stable) to using an unstable one (Flutter 1.2.2 • channel dev). The part I don't understand is that for me the charts_flutter dependency 0.6.0 was working fine until I upgraded the Flutter plugin from 33.1.1 to 33.3.1 ... not so sure what that upgrade did, any idea?

Comment: I doubt it was related to the Flutter plugin. I assume you run `flutter packages upgrade` and the dependency constraints allowed newer package versions that are not compatible with your SDK.

Comment: I also doubt that, and maybe the _flutter packages upgrade_ was triggered by the Studio plugin upgrade, but what really bothers me is that before whatever update, I had charts_flutter 0.6.0 running against Flutter 1.0.0 (stable) and now I can't figure it out how that was actually possible :)

Comment: Perhaps charts_common made an update and didn't do the right version increment when they limited the SDK version to `>= 2.1.0`

Comment: Bingo! Thanks to help me to figure this out: https://github.com/google/charts/issues/212